# Google chrom wrong number character

Tags: google-chrome, character-encoding, localization

After a few releases of google chrome browser a new bug appeared which was not in previous versions.
I have a web page which shows date and time in Arabic characters.
there is a picture:
[image: numbers between two slashes are in other languages]
it was just fine before updates, and it is fine in other browsers.
I don't know if the problem is from my code (not defining some thing) or it's chrome new bug.

> and notice that I use a localizer for **Iran**.
>   and therefor my fonts are Persian and using UTF-8 char-set
>   **note** that just number between two *slashes* or two *dots* change and etc.